# There are 3 method "this.add.rectangle()", "new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle()" and "fillRectShape()", when should I use which?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser 3 and trying to figure out the difference between the (at least) 3 methods to create rectangles. Here is the code

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
  scene: {
    create: create
  }
});

function create() {
  let rect1 = this.add.rectangle(300, 100, 100, 30, 0x00f000, .5);

  let rect2 = new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(this, 300, 150, 100, 30, 0xf00000)
  this.add.existing(rect2);

  let rect3 = this.add.graphics({
    fillStyle: {
      color: 0x00f0f0
    }
  });
  let rect = new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(300, 200, 100, 30);
  rect3.fillRectShape(rect);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

`rect1` uses the simplest one which just needs 1 line of code.

`rect2` instantiates the `Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle` class. I guess it's more powerful if I need a bunch of rectangle-like objects where I can create a subclass of the class, predefine some properties and methods and instantiate my customized rectangle-like object.

`rect3` uses `Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics` which I cannot image its use case where it beats the previous two. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short Answer:**

- if you need a Rectangle for bounderies or other calculations or so use: `new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(...)`
- if you need a simple rectangle **GameObject** use: `this.add.rectangle(...)`

  - if you don't want to add it into the scene right away use: `new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(...)`
- if you need *special rectangle*  **GameObject**  with more *bells and whistles* use: `this.add.graphics(...)`

**The long Answer:**

It depends on the tasks at hand. Since each Object creates more or less a differnet Object with different properties/methods.

- Type `Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics`:
  Is a **GameObject** but very "lowlevel", you can paint almost anything on it. like rectanlges, circles, ... but it's more work.
  *Details can be found here https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics.html*

> **Here an example** of a *special* rectangle: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/graphics/fill-rounded-rectangle

- Type `Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle`:
  Is a **GameObject** as the `Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics`, but is specialized for creating rectangles.
  `this.add.rectangle(...)` and `new Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle(...)` create both a rectangle of this type. `this.add.rectangle` is only a more convenient way to achive this, and adds it straight to the current scene.
  *Details can be found here  https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Rectangle.html)*

> **Here an example** of *basic* rectangles: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/shapes/rectangle

- Type `Phaser.Geom.Rectangle`:
  Is a geometric *Shape*, good for bounderies and/or other calculations *(but you can also draw with it)*.
  *Details can be found here https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Rectangle.html*

> **Here an example** of how it is used to check if an **GameObject** is in a specific rectangle: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/geom/rectangle/contains-rect